# Are Sessions part of Http 1.1 or is it a server feature?

Tags: java, php, http, session, servlets

Http is known as stateless, but most Java has a Session attached to each Servlet. There is also a Session in PHP since at least 2002 and I guess it's the same in all application servers.

With Apache Server, we use a JSESSION_ID, with maybe a cluster name, that points to the right session in the Java server. Nevertheless mod_session exists only since Apache 2.3.

I have looked at some RFC ([2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt), [2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965), [6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)) but it doesn't look at first sight mandatory to Http 1.1.

Are sessions a bonus feature ? Same for Cookies ?

Comment: Sessions are in fact just a cookie that's used to identify session data, it's all server side features.

Comment: @JameyD Sessions are not cookies, just that a *session id* is stored at client-side using *session cookies*. If a browser has its cookies disabled the server can still maintain a session by falling back on *url rewriting*.